# MAMP phpmyadmin db files not in the expected location

Tags: mysql, database, macos, mamp

For some reason MAMP, mySQL server and phpMyAdmin started acting odd.

First some back story....

First off in MAMP the mySQL Server indicator was not on (although it's on in system prefs) and when launching phpMyAdmin I was getting the error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.

Step-1 After some google-foo – I symbolic linked /tmp/mysql.sock to /var/mysql/mysql.sock – then error changed to:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Step-2 Bit more google-foo – in MAMP I changed the mysql to 3306 – and then error changed to:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Step-3 Bit more google-foo – I used terminal and changed the password to 'root' which is what the MAMP start page said the mysql password should be.

Working.

Step-5 Rebooted mac. Not working again and back to error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory.

Step-6 Checked the symbolic links from step 1 and now tmp/mysql now points to MAMP/tmp/mysql/

Step-7 Bit more google-foo – changed localhost to 127.0.0.1 in MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

So I am now into phpMyAdmin, although the MAMP mySQL Server indicator is still not on. When I go into phpMyAdmin non of my databases are listed.

Step-8 Rebooted mac. Still no databases listed and MAMP mySQL Server indicator still off.

Step-9 So I created a new DB and tried to find that in the Finder, which I did in usr/local/mysql/data – although I was locked out of 'data' until I changed it's permissions to 755. (usr/local/mysql is actually sym linked to usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64)

So the question is now how to get MAMP/phpMyAdmin to point to the db files in MAMP/db/mysql56 and not usr/local/mysql/data

Create a symbolic link?

I have reinstalled MAMP which has made no difference.

Comment: I have copied MAMP/db/mysql56 to usr/local/mysql/ and renamed it data – then changes it's and it's contained folders owner/group to _mysql and all my databases are now showing in phpMyAdmin. Now I just need to get WP to find the db...

Comment: I'm now getting "Error establishing a database connection", in wp-config I've tried the hostname as 'localhost', 'localhost:3306', '127.0.0.1:3306' and '127.0.0.1'

Comment: 'localhost:8888' does work and '127.0.0.1:8888' just hangs with waiting for localhost in the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have two different MySQL servers running on your system. That would explain why the MAMP status is showing that MySQL isn't running, but you're still able to connect and would also explain why you're not seeing existing database when you connect. This is further reinforced by the paths; `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64` doesn't seem like a MAMP path (though I don't use MAMP, so I don't know for sure).

You should examine your system for another MySQL installation. You might try `which mysql` at the command line, or `which mysqld` which might give some clue where it's running from. Once you find the second MySQL installation, I suggest removing it entirely (while maintaining the data directory that you need), because no good can come from having two different MySQL installations fighting for the same resources.

An alternative explanation would be that you're not connecting as an actual user, but as the anonymous user, which could hide all the normal databases from your view.

Comment: I have removed the mysql running from /user/local. When I open MAMP it still doesn't active the MySQL Server like it use to when it launches. In prefs it says MySQL is version 5.6.35 – so it can see something? In the phpinfo page it's pointing to the mysqli.default_socket in MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock BUT mysqli.default_host, mysqli.default_pw and mysqli.default_user are set to 'no value'. Just trying to install mamp on another computer to see if this is relevant. When I open phpmyadmin now I'm back to getting "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused"

Comment: mysqli.default_host, mysqli.default_pw and mysqli.default_user are set to 'no value' are teh defualt values set on a fresh install of MAMP

Comment: access via mamp phpLiteAdmin is working but not phpMyAdmin

Comment: okay getting somewhere. I renamed MAMP/db and used a fresh copy without any of my databases included and it's working. now I just need to add back all my db's

Comment: luckily just moving each database folder across worked. All up and running. must have been something corrupt in MAMP/db/mysql56 + the two mysql installations. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.